# Would you recommend me a text book reference?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

I am searching for a text book reference or lecture notes, where I can find the following theorem:
I mean as similar as possible to the statement with these same words (if possible). Or including these 3 equivalences:

**THEOREM:** Let $M\subset H$, orthonormal, are equivalents

a) $M$ is total basis (or orthonormal basis or Hilbert basis);

b) For all $u \in H\quad  \sum_{i\in Ju}$, $(u, u_i)u_i=u$ where $Ju=\{i\in J: u_i\in M \; \text{and} \; (u_i, u)\neq 0\}$

c) $\sum_{i\in J_u} |(u, u_i)|^2=|u|^2$, for all $u \in H$ (Parseval identity)

**Remark:** I wish this because I'm studying using Brezis' book, however there is appearing in different theorems, and it is not including the $\iff$ (equivalence).

Comment: Any text on functional analysis should have this. I use Kreyszig personally since it is a bit kinder to undergrads, but any should do. (I didn't downvote but you haven't provided any motivation for why you want this and what you have looked at).

Comment: That's what I don't understand in most cases, why they are downvoting,this isn't the first post I have seen that.

Comment: Question is: why not simply __understand__ the THEOREM instead of asking for even more references? As a student in ancient times, I figured out such elementary things all by myself. I didn't vote, but I'm not suprised that the downvotes are there.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I understand your position, I do not disagree. However, it is very well known that there are people that are better to teach compared with others, the same can be applied to authors of books around the world. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bit more of that theorem can be found in the page 108 of **Fourier and Wavelet Analysis** By *Bachmann, Narici, Beckenstein*.

[image]

or in the page 346 of

*Roman, Steven*, Advanced linear algebra, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 135. New York: Springer-Verlag. xii, 363 p. (1992). [ZBL0754.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0754.15002).[image]

Answer (score 2):

A reference which might be useful: paper S. Gudder: "Inner product spaces", https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1974.11993493

Answer (score 1):

The result is a combination of Theorem 4.14 and Theorem 4.18 from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition.